# Can the value of both the current and next item be accessed in a Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

Let's say I want to built a list of tuples from a given list. Is there any way of doing this with a list comprehension, or do I need to resort to a for loop?

```
[a,b,c,d,e] => [(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(d,e)]
```

Comment: There is a way of doing this with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> [(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)]
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e')]
```

with zip:

```
>>> zip(l,l[1:])
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e')]
```

--
Edited according to comments

Comment: Just `zip(l, l[1:])` will do.

Comment: Very nice and Pythonic solution, in that it doesn't refer directly to anything other than the list object itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but it's easy to do given a loop index, e.g.:

```
l='''a,b,c,d,e'''.split(',')
[(l[x],l[x+1]) for x in range(len(l)-1)]
```

Outputs:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e')]
```

EDIT: Looks like several of us came up with this identical solution simultaneously...